# Bad Request 400 - Usando API Fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, sequelize-js, fetch

Estou com problemas ao acessar minha api usando `POST method`.
Esta é minha requisição:

```
function createTool(token, obj) {
  return fetch(`${url}/tools`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: token,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(obj),
  })
    .then(async (response) => await response.json());
}
```

Esta é a resposta do meu back-end:

```
XHRPOSThttp://localhost:3000/tools
[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 17ms]
    error   "Field 'title' doesn't have a default value"
```

Em meu console o Back-End retorna a execução corretamente. Porém, o objeto de inserção está vazio.

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `tools` (`id`) VALUES (DEFAULT);
```

Onde estou cometendo o erro ao passar o valores?

Comment: Me parece que não é possível reproduzir o problema somente com essas informações, qual o banco de dados utilizado? Qual seu schema? Como o back-end trata a requisição? Talvez editar sua pergunta com essas informações te ajude com a ter uma resposta, veja mais em [mcve]

Comment: essa exception está vindo do próprio sql, sua tabela 'tools' tem o campo 'title' non nullable, está tentando inserir nulo e ela está avisando que não tem um valor default pra preencher

Comment: Todas as vezes que eu tive esse problema de chegar no back o objeto vazio, foi que o objeto que o back está preparado pra receber não está igual o que o front está enviando. Tipo, às vezes o front envia um campo cnpj em string, e o back recebe em int. Ou vice versa. Reveja seu objeto toos e as tipagens deles, em relação ao objeto que o back recebe e as tipagens.
int, tem que receber int, string com string, e assim sucessivamente.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver especificando o tipo do arquivo do recurso em meu `header`.

A requisição ficou assim:

```
function createTool(token, tool) {
  return fetch(`${url}/tools`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',u
      Authorization: token,
    }, 
    body: JSON.stringify(tool),
  })
    .then(async (response) => await response.json());
}
```

Agradeço pelas dicas no comentários.